# Display Dynamics CRM Content in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, dynamics-crm

**How would I go about surfacing dynamics CRM content within SharePoint** i.e. Display details on a account stored in CRM

I have very little knowledge on CRM. Is there a CRM REST endpoint? How does authentication work - both of these environments will be in the same domain.

Ideally I would like to develop a client side solution that sits in SharePoint and pulls data from CRM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are onpremises, there are several options and they do depend on the version of CRM you are running.

If you are running a recent version, you could call the CRM WebApi, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx

As you are on-premises you should be able to just call the api and authenticate automatically with the current user. Maybe you need to figure out the 'internal' url of CRM to make this work without the need to authenticate. If CRM is an IFD (internet facing deployment) and ADFS is used then you don't want the 'default' url but the url that doesn't use ADFS for authentication.

To test you could just put this api in an ajax call in a Script Editor webpart and see if it works:

```
http://[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.0/contacts?$top=10
```